How to activate 'right click - > open in new tab" on a JS link?
i have a website with clickable columns, but i can't right click them and open in new tab. I found a function that i believe is responsible for turning columns into links. Is there a possibility to add some code to this function or modify it to enable 'right click' functionality?
    $.fn.avia_link_column = function()
    {
        return this.each( function()
        {
            $(this).on( 'click', function(e)
            {
                //  if event is bubbled from an <a> link, do not activate link of column/cell
                if( 'undefined' !== typeof e.target && 'undefined' !== typeof e.target.href )
                {
                    return;
                }

                var column = $(this),
                    url = column.data('link-column-url'),
                    target = column.data('link-column-target'),
                    link = window.location.hostname+window.location.pathname;

                if( 'undefined' === typeof url || 'string' !== typeof url )
                {
                    return;
                }

                if( 'undefined' !== typeof target || '_blank' == target )
                {
//                  in FF and other browsers this opens a new window and not only a new tab
//                  window.open( url, '_blank', 'noopener noreferrer' );
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = url;
                    a.target = '_blank';
                    a.rel = 'noopener noreferrer';
                    a.click();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //  allow smoothscroll feature when on same page and hash exists - trigger only works for current page
                    if( column.hasClass('av-cell-link') || column.hasClass('av-column-link') )
                    {
                        var reader = column.hasClass('av-cell-link') ? column.prev('a.av-screen-reader-only').first() : column.find('a.av-screen-reader-only').first();

                        url = url.trim();
                        if( ( 0 == url.indexOf("#") ) || ( ( url.indexOf( link ) >= 0 ) && ( url.indexOf("#") > 0 ) ) )
                        {
                            reader.trigger('click');

                            //  fix a bug with tabsection not changeing tab
                            if( 'undefined' == typeof target || '_blank' != target )
                            {
                                window.location.href = url;
                            }

                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    window.location.href = url;
                }

                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            });
        });
    };

Tried to find answers on the web but without success.
